# "Lost connection to MySQL server during query" with venv

Tags: python, mysql, django

I don’t know why. When I don’t use the virtual environment, everything is normal, and the error "Lost connection to MySQL server during query" appears when I use the virtual environment.

I tested that using "manage shell" in a virtual environment to perform model data operations is also working properly

Python3.6.9
Django2.2
mysql 5.7

```
Internal Server Error: /sap/base/v1/token_by_code/get_token/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jay/fs_work_django_dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 240, in _commit
    return self.connection.commit()
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jay/fs_work_django_dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/jay/fs_work_django_dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/jay/fs_work_django_dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/python3.6/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 52, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/python3.6/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 52, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/python3.6/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 52, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/jay/fs_work_django_dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py", line 240, in __exit__
    connection.commit()
  File "/home/jay/fs_work_django_dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 262, in commit
    self._commit()
  File "/home/jay/fs_work_django_dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 240, in _commit
    return self.connection.commit()
  File "/home/jay/fs_work_django_dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/jay/fs_work_django_dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 240, in _commit
    return self.connection.commit()
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')
```

Comment: Error `2013` suggests that your connection times out. So can you confirm you are initially connecting to your DB, prior to any queries? Or if you are connecting, is the query taking more time than you have configured for your `connect_timeout` value?

Comment: There is no such situation. If this is the case, I think the same error will occur when venv is not used, but this error only occurs when venv is used.